# Migrate existing sonarqube as a service from windows 2016 server to windows 2019 server

Tags: java, windows, server, sonarqube, migrate

I need to Migrate the existing Sonarqube as a service from Windows 2016 server to Windows 2019 server I installed Java, set the path, installed the same version on the existing server, copied the config and data files, set up the env variables to be the same way the existing server but Sonarqube will not start. Its database is SQL on a separate server.

I installed java, set the path,installed the same version on the existing server, copied the config and data files, set up the env variables to be the same way the existing server but sonarqube will not start. Its database is a sql on a separate server.